# Material UI Override Step Icon Style

Tags: material-ui

Using "@material-ui/core" at version 3.1.0

It's pretty easy to override globally a stepper icon's color **globally**

```
createMuiTheme({
   overrides: {
     MuiStepIcon: {
       root: {
         color: "#F00"
       },
     }
   }
})
```

However, it's not clear how you would override the only the color for an icon for either a StepButton or StepLabel using the [recommended methods](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/). I see that you can pass in your own icon element, but I don't want to replicate the library logic for the step number and the checkmark.

Is there an clean way to do this?

Comment: Just a suggestion... you might consider changing the title to "Material UI Override Step Icon Styles" since this applies to all styles

Answer (score 15, accepted):

StepLabel provides a `StepIconProps` property that allows you pass custom props to the `StepIcon` component. ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/step-label/#props))

You can use the `classes` prop to customize StepIcon styles.

```js
<Step key={label}>
  <StepLabel 
    StepIconProps={{ 
      classes: { root: classes.icon } 
    }}
  >
    {label} 
  </StepLabel>
</Step>
```

[image: Edit Material UI - override step icon color]

**Non-linear steppers**

You can nest a `StepLabel` component inside `StepButton` when you need to pass custom props to `StepIcon.` ([docs](https://material-ui.com/api/step-button/#props))

```js
<Step key={label}>
  <StepButton
    onClick={this.handleStep(index)}
    completed={this.state.completed[index]}
  >
    <StepLabel
      StepIconProps={{ classes: { root: classes.icon } }}
    >
      {label}
    </StepLabel>
  </StepButton>
</Step>
```

[image: Edit Material UI - StepButton override icon color]

Comment: Awesome! This works well with StepLabel. StepIconProps can't be passed to a StepButton; it looks like StepButton creates it's own props object that can't be overridden. Do you have any insight for that one?

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks Luke!

Comment: Interesting that you need to use `!important` for the color property to work, thanks for your help!

Comment: how do you  do conditional styling based on if it's the active step or not?

Comment: @Jared  My solution for that was:  ```const labelClass = index <= currentStep ? classes.active : classes.icon;```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem, So I Raised the [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27387) in Mui repo, received this reply- we are not using the Mui-active and Mui-completed class in v4, In v5 you should use the Mui-active and Mui-completed classes.

So according to them this will fix the issue for now-
Declare style like this -

```
stepIconRoot: {
    color: "pink",
    "&.MuiStepIcon-active": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "&.MuiStepIcon-completed": {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
```

and put this inside `<Step> </Step>`

```
<StepLabel
    StepIconProps={{
        classes: {root: classes.stepIconRoot}
        }}>
     {label}
</StepLabel>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-override-step-icon-color-forked-rcpqw?file=/demo.js:3095-3456

Answer (score 1):

To apply these changes as global you can use the following

```
createMuiTheme({
overrides: {
    MuiStepIcon: {
        root: {
            color: "#F00",

            "&$active": {
                color: "#C4E90C"
            },

            "&$completed": {
            color: "#C4E90C"
            }
        },
    }
}
```

})